# Static vs instance methods of str in Python

Tags: python, string

So, I have learnt that strings have a center method.

```
>>> 'a'.center(3)
' a '
```

Then I have noticed that I can do the same thing using the 'str' object which is a type, since

```
>>> type(str)
<type 'type'>
```

Using this 'type' object I could access the string methods like they were static functions.

```
>>> str.center('a',5)
'  a  '
```

Alas! This violates the zen of python.

**There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.**

Even the types of these two methods are different.

```
>>> type(str.center)
<type 'method_descriptor'>
>>> type('Ni!'.center)
<type 'builtin_function_or_method'>
```

Now,

1. Is this an example of how classes in python should be designed?
2. Why are the types different?
3. What is a method_descriptor and why should I bother?

**Thanks for the answers!**

Comment: [Understanding `__get__` and `__set__` and Python descriptors](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3798835/3821804)

Answer (score 19):

That's simply how classes in Python work:

```
class C:
    def method(self, arg):
        print "In C.method, with", arg

o = C()
o.method(1)
C.method(o, 1)
# Prints:
# In C.method, with 1
# In C.method, with 1
```

When you say `o.method(1)` you can think of it as a shorthand for `C.method(o, 1)`.  A `method_descriptor` is part of the machinery that makes that work.

Comment: More accurately, when you access o.method, you get a wrapper function that's bound directly to o.  This is one of the most useful properties of Python.

Answer (score 9):

> There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.

Philosophically speaking, there *is* only one obvious way to do it: 'a'.center(3). The fact that there is an unobvious way of calling any method (i.e. the well-explained-by-previous-commentors o.method(x) and Type.method(o, x)) which is useful in many contexts is perfectly in line with the zen of python.

Your homework assignment is to read Guido's [Why the Explicit Self Has to Stay](http://neopythonic.blogspot.com/2008/10/why-explicit-self-has-to-stay.html).

Answer (score 5):

To expand on RichieHindle's answer:

In Python, all methods on a class idiomatically take a "self" parameter.  For example:

```
def method(self, arg): pass
```

That "self" argument tells Python what instance of the class the method is being called on. When you call a method on a class instance, this is typically passed implicitly for you:

```
o.method(1)
```

However, you also have the option of using the class Object, and explicitly passing in the class instance:

```
C.method(o, 1)
```

To to use your string example, str.center is a method on the str object:

```
"hi".center(5)
```

is equivalent to:

```
str.center("hi", 5)
```

You are passing in the str instance "hi" to the object, explicitly doing what's normally implicit.

Answer (score 2):

```
'a'.center(3) == str.center('a',3)
```

There *is* only one way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Method descriptor is a normal class with `__get__`, `__set__` and `__del__` methods.

When, e.g., `__get__` is called, it is passed 2 or 3 arguments:

- `self`, which is the descriptor class itself,
- `inst`, which is the caller objet to which the "described" method should be bound,
- `cls`, which can be `None`.

To illustrate method_descriptor machinery, let me give this example:

```
class Descriptor(object):
    def __init__(self, m):
    self._meth=m

    def __get__(self, inst, cls=None):
        if cls is None: cls=type(inst)
        delattr(cls,self._meth.func_name)
        def _inst_meth(*a):
            return self._meth(inst,*a)
        return _inst_meth

def instanceonlymethod(f):
    return Descriptor(f)

class Test(object):
    def meth_1(self,*a):
        return '-'.join(str(i) for i in a)

    @instanceonlymethod
    def meth_2(self,*a):
        return '-'.join(str(i) for i in a)

t=Test()
print t.meth_1(2,3,4,5) #returns: 2-3-4-5
print Test.meth_1(t,1,2,3,4) #returns: 1-2-3-4
print t.meth_2(2,3,4,5) #returns: 2-3-4-5
try:
    print Test.meth_2(t,1,2,3,4)
except Exception, why: #for 2.6, see changes
    print why #returns: type object 'Test' has no attribute 'meth_2'
```

Now, when you call `Test.meth_2(t, 1,2,3,4)`, it won't work.