# What are the differences amongst Python's "__get*__" and "_del*__" methods?

Tags: python, getter-setter, standard-library, accessor

I just started learning Python a few months ago, and I'm trying to understand the differences between the different `__get*__` methods:

```
__get__
__getattr__
__getattribute__
__getitem___
```

And their `__del*__` equivalents:

```
__del__
__delattr__
__delete__
__delitem__
```

What are the differences between these? When should I use one over the other? Is there a specific reason why most of the `__get*__` methods have `__set*__` equivalents, but there is no `__setattribute__`?

Comment: The documentation doesn't list them "side by side" as in "horizontally", but it does have all of them on a single page and all except the `{get,set}item` ones (which stand out by featuring `item`) are right next to each other vertically, in two small sections. Some of those names *are* too terse/similar, but it's not as bad as you make it sound.

Comment: Yep, I realized about 20 minutes ago that they ARE in fact all on one page.  Sorry about that—my mistake.  **However:** I am still confused.  I thought I was clear that I **have** read the documentation, and I’m still having trouble drawing a clear definition between the special method names.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The documentation for every method that you listed is easly reachable from the [documentation index](http://docs.python.org/py3k/genindex-_.html) .

Anyway this may be a little extended reference:

#### `__get__`, `__set__` and `__del__` are descriptors

*"In a nutshell, a descriptor is a way to customize what happens when you reference an attribute on a model."*  [[official doc link]](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors)

They are well explained around, so here there are some references:

- Python Descriptors by Marty Alchin [Part 1](http://martyalchin.com/2007/nov/23/python-descriptors-part-1-of-2/) and [Part 2](http://martyalchin.com/2007/nov/24/python-descriptors-part-2-of-2/)
- SO question [Understanding __get__ and __set__ and Python descriptors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3798835/1132524)
- [google](http://www.google.com/search?q=python%20descriptor)

#### `__getattr__`, `__getattribute__`, `__setattr__`, `__delattr__`

Are methods that *can be defined to customize the meaning of attribute access (use of, assignment to, or deletion of `x.name`) for class instances.* [[official doc link]](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-attribute-access)

Example 1:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 10
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return name

f = Foo()
f.x    # -> 10
f.bar   # -> 'bar'
```

Example 2:

```
class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 10
    def __getattr__(self,name):
        return name
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        if name == 'bar':
            raise AttributeError
        return 'getattribute'

f = Foo()
f.x    # -> 'getattribute'
f.baz    # -> 'getattribute'
f.bar    # -> 'bar'
```

#### `__getitem__`, `__setitem__`, `__delitem__`

Are methods that *can be defined to implement container objects.* [[official doc link]](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-attribute-access)

Example:

```
class MyColors:
    def __init__(self):
        self._colors = {'yellow': 1, 'red': 2, 'blue': 3}
    def __getitem__(self, name):
        return self._colors.get(name, 100)

colors = MyColors()
colors['yellow']   # -> 1
colors['brown']    # -> 100
```

I hope this is enough to give you a general idea.

Comment: (1) I realized about 25 minutes before I found your answer that these are in fact all documented on one page.  Sorry for that error in my original question.  (2) **Thank you!!** The articles by Marty Alchin  are written extremely well.  And they clarified something huge I wasn’t getting—that `__get__` and `__set__` are supposed to be defined _in the attributes_, and not in the class!  I still think all the methods in my original post could do with more differentiable names, but I suddenly feel a lot less overwhelmed.  Thank you. ☺

Comment: @Zearin: There's a good article about [Python Attributes and Methods](http://www.cafepy.com/article/python_attributes_and_methods/python_attributes_and_methods.html) maybe it can interest you. *(fixed link)*

Comment: @RikPoggi You are actually not saying, why `__get__` when we have `__getattr__` or vice verca. answer you mentioned for both are same

Comment: Thanks for the examples and link to docs. Would be nice to explicitly mention how we get from `AttributeError` to `__getattr__` in a `# comment`, and perhaps also that, unlike `__setattr__` and `__getattribute__`, `__getattr__` is only invoked if the name is not defined, or through an `AttributeError`. At least that's my understanding.