# How to use get/set methods?

Tags: python, getter-setter

Please point where a bug in my code.

```
class Foo:
    def get(self):
        return self.a

    def set(self, a):
        self.a = a

Foo.set(10)
Foo.get()
```

**TypeError: set() takes exactly 2 positional arguments (1 given)**

How to use `__get__()`/`__set__()`?

Comment: Of course you should include `self.a = 0` or something like that in the `__init__` method, too.  Also, you should not use trivial getters/setters in Python.  Just change it directly:  `Foo().a = 42`.  If you have to validate your input, you should use `property.setter`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are instance methods. You have to create an instance of `Foo` first:

```
f = Foo()
f.set(10)
f.get()    # Returns 10
```

Comment: Thank you! Tell what is `__ get__ ()` / `__get__ ()`?

Comment: @Opsa: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3798835/understanding-get-and-set-and-python-descriptors

Answer (score 3):

> How to use `__get__()/__set__()`?

Like this if you have Python3. Descriptors in Python2.6 doesn't want works properly for me.

Python v2.6.6

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __get__(*args): print 'get'
...     def __set__(*args): print 'set'
...
>>> class Bar:
...     foobar = Foo()
...
>>> x = Bar()
>>> x.foobar
get
>>> x.foobar = 2
>>> x.foobar
2
```

Python v3.2.2

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __get__(*args): print('get')
...     def __set__(*args): print('set')
...
>>> class Bar:
...     foobar = Foo()
...
>>> x = Bar()
>>> x.foobar
get
>>> x.foobar = 2
set
>>> x.foobar
get
```

Comment: `__get__` and `__set__` have **nothing to do with** Java-style getters and setters as a programming concept; OP asked two completely separate questions, due to confusion and a lack of understanding of the fundamentals. Someone who cannot distinguish classes from instances is not going to benefit from an explanation of the descriptor protocol. Aside from that, Python has supported `property` since 2.2. (Anyway, the problem in your 2.x attempt is that `Bar` also needs to inherit from `object` explicitly, since old-style classes in 2.x are weird like that.)