# Python 3.x: Object Not Accepting Definition?

Tags: python

Ok, so I have this class that's supposed to have `food`, `hunger`, and some other attributes.

I have just a definition like this:

```
def setfood():
     choice = input("Choice: ")
     if choice == "1":
           food = 1
           bored = 2
     if choice == "2":
           food = 4
           bored = 8
     return food
     return bored
```

And then I have this class like this.

```
class thing(object):
    def __init__(self, name, hunger = 0, boredom = 0):
        self.name = name
        self.hunger = hunger
        self.boredom = boredom

    def eat(self):
       setfood()
       self.hunger -= food
       self.boredom += bored
```

Well, no matter what I do, I can't get it to work. I kept getting this error about a global variable.

Well, I add in `food = 0` and `bored = 0` into the main part of the program and it makes no difference because I can't pass the global variables into the definition.

I tried to add the definition into my class and it still made no difference. I also tried to make separate definitions to return each variables...also didn't work. No matter what I do, I can't win.

The only way I can get it to work is if I do this:

```
food = setfood()
```

I thought I could maybe change it to this:

```
food = setfood(food)
food = setfood(bored)
```

But that doesn't work either...

But, if I do that for both variables, I have to go through the whole thing twice. So what exactly do I do? I'm so lost and frustrated.

Comment: Is the function above supposed to be `setfood`?

Comment: you can't return from a method twice. (`return food return bored`)

Comment: I tried changing it to (return food, bored) and I still get "NameError: global name 'food' is not defined"

Comment: `setfood()` works because it's a function that doesn't take any variables.  post the traceback and we'll be able to help you more

Comment: see my answer, it may help a bit

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 26, in <module>
    main()
  File "", line 24, in main
    creat.eat()
  File "", line 9, in eat
    self.hunger -= food
NameError: global name 'food' is not defined

Comment: I ended up just adding it to the attribute and it worked...but I'm still curious to know if there's some way to use a definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "NameError: global name 'food' is not defined"

`food` in your function is only defined when you enter one of the `if` blocks. Are you entering input other than 1 or 2? If os `food` won't be defined to anything. You could have a default value for `food` like:

```
food = 0 # food stays at 0 for invalid choices
choice = input("Choice: ")
if choice == "1":
     food = 1
     bored = 2
if choice == "2":
     food = 4
     bored = 8
return food
```

Also to return two variables your return statements need to return a tuple, ie

```
 return (food, bored)
```

then the caller can do

```
 (food, bored) = setfood()
```

and you'll be able to return two values at once as you intend

Answer (score 0):

```
def setfood():
```

Is a set method. It should not have to return anything. You should define other methods like getfood() or getboredStatus() to return food status or bored status.
See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9316598/how-to-use-get-set-methods) for more info