# Confusion about __get__ and __call__ in python

Tags: python

See the simple example below:

```
class Celsius(object):
    def __init__(self, value=0.0):
        self.value = float(value)
    def __get__(self, instance, owner): 
         return self.value 
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
         self.value = float(value)
    def __call__(self):
         print('__call__ called')

class Temperature(object):
    celsius = Celsius()
    def __init__(self):
       self.celsius1 = Celsius()


T = Temperature()
print('T.celsius:', T.celsius)
print('T.celsius1:', T.celsius1)

output
T.celsius: 0.0
T.celsius1: <__main__.Celsius object at 0x023544F0>
```

I wonder why they have different output.
I know `T.celsius` will call the `__get__` and `T.celsius1` call the `__call__`.

Comment: And so, you yourself answered your own question.

Comment: Very good question. I had to check the documentation. Pretty confusing behaviour, IMO.

Comment: I don't see a `__call__` call...

Answer (score 9):

The differences lie in the fact the the first attribute is a *class* attribute while the second is an *instance* attribute.

As per [the documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors), If an object that implements at least the first of the `Descriptor` methods (`__get__`, `__set__` and `__delete__`) is held in a *class* attribute, its `__get__` method will be called when accessed. This is not the case with an *instance* attribute. You can learn more [from the howto](http://docs.python.org/howto/descriptor.html).

The `__call__` method of an object only comes into play when the object is invoked like a function:

```
>>> class Foo:
...    def __call__(self):
...        return "Hello there!"
...
>>> f = Foo()
>>> f() 
'Hello There!'
```

Comment: Please write when (and why) invoke object as a function.

Comment: @ProblemFactory [Advanced decorator usage](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators), for example. Passing an object into a `map`, `filter` or `reduce` function for advanced capabilities. Smart dynamic dispatch. Code instrumentation. Monkey patching. The list goes on, and on, and on...

Comment: Also on and on goes the inconsistency, complexity and ugliness of the Python language

Answer (score 3):

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors):

> The following methods only apply when an instance of the class
>   containing the method (a so-called descriptor class) appears in an
>   owner class (the descriptor must be in either the owner’s class
>   dictionary or in the class dictionary for one of its parents).

So descriptors (ie. objects that implement `__get__`, `__set__` or `__delete__`) must be members of a class, NOT an instance.

With the followinging changes:

```
Temperature.celsius2 = Celsius()

T = Temperature()
print('T.celsius:', T.celsius)
print('T.celsius1:', T.celsius1)
print('T.celsius2:', T.celsius2)
```

The output is:

```
T.celsius: 0.0
T.celsius1: <__main__.Celsius object at 0x7fab8c8d0fd0>
T.celsius2:, 0.0
```

More links:

- [Descriptor HowTo Guide](http://docs.python.org/howto/descriptor.html).
- [Understanding __get__ and __set__ and Python descriptors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3798835/understanding-get-and-set-and-python-descriptors)
- http://martyalchin.com/2007/nov/23/python-descriptors-part-1-of-2/
- https://www.google.com/?q=python%20descriptors

Answer (score 2):

`T.celcius` as an attribute of the class `Temperature` so it returns the result of the `__get__` method of T.celcius as expected.

`T.celsius1` is an attribute of the instance `T` so it returns the variable itself since descriptors are only invoked for new style objects or classes.

The `__call__` method would be used if you were to do `T.celsius()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you try that, you will see same result.

```
print('T.celsius:', T.celsius)
print('T.celsius1:', T.celsius1.value)
```

[What is the purpose of self?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/python-self-explained)

Answer (score 0):

As others said, descriptor instances are meant to be used as class attributes.

```
class Temperature(object):
    celsius = Celsius()
    def __init__(self):
       self.celsius1 = Celsius()
```

If you want `self.celsius1` to have custom behavior, override [`__getattr__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) method:

```
class Temperature(object):
    celsius = Celsius()
    def __getattr__(self, name):
       if name == 'celsius1':
           return ...
```