# What is the difference between __set__ and __setattr__ in Python and when should which be used?

Tags: python, attributes, getter-setter

As the title says.

Coming from Java im used to:

```
private int A;

public void setA(int A) {
    this.A = A;
}

public int getA() {
    return this.A
}
```

How do I do that (if I need to) in Python.
And if one of `__setattr__` or `__set__` is used for this, what is the other one used for?

Edit:
I feel I need to clarify. I know that in Python one doe's not create setters and getters before they are needed.

Lets say I want to do something like this:

```
public void setA(int A) {
    update_stuff(A);
    and_calculate_some_thing(A);
    this.A = A;
}
```

What is the "pythonic" way to implement this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In python, something like this *should* be implemented using a `property` (and then only when they do something useful).

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = None

    @property
    def x(self):
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self,y):
        self._x = y
```

In this example, it would be better to just do (as pointed out by Edward):

```
class Foo(object):
     def __init__(self):
         self.x = None
```

since our getter/setter methods don't actually do anything ... However, properties become very useful when the setter/getter actually does something more than just assign/return an attribute's value.

It could also be implemented using `__setattr__`/`__getattr__` (but it shouldn't be implemented this way as it quickly becomes cumbersome if your class has more than 1 property.  I would also guess that doing it this way would be slower than using properties):

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self._x = None
    def __setattr__(self,attr,obj):
        if(attr == 'x'):
            object.__setattr__(self,'_x',obj)
        else:
            object.__setattr__(self,attr,obj)

    def __getattr__(self,attr):
        if(attr == 'x'):
            return object.__getattr__(self,'_x')
        else:
            return object.__getattr__(self,attr)
```

In terms of what `__setattr__` and `__getattr__` actually do...
`__setattr__`/`__getattr__` are what are called when you do something like:

```
myclassinstance = MyClass()
myclassinstance.x = 'foo'  #translates to MyClass.__setattr__(myclassinstance,'x','foo')
bar = myclassinstance.x    #translates to bar=MyClass.__getattr__(myclassinstance,'x')
```

As for `__get__` and `__set__`:  [previous posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3798835/understanding-get-and-set-and-python-descriptors) have discussed that quite nicely.

Note that in python *there is no such thing as private variables*.  In general, in a class member is prefixed with an underscore, you shouldn't mess with it (unless you know what you're doing of course).  If it's prefixed with 2 underscores, it will invoke name-mangling which makes it harder to access outside the class.  This is used to prevent namespace clashes in inheritance (and those variables are generally also not to be messed with).

Comment: Good illustration of properties, but could be better with an explanation of why you should use a property over setattr/getattr

Comment: @Greg : I think that looking at the above code, if you have more than one property it becomes obvious which one is easier to maintain -- especially if you're doing more than just a simple `setattr`/`getattr` inside your property setters/getters.

Comment: I don't disagree at all, but clarity is rarely a bad thing.  +1

Comment: So if I would like to calculate something when a attribute is changed I should use a property because of clarity. But __setattr__ could (int theory) be used as well.

Answer (score 9):

`__set__()` is used in descriptors when the descriptor is assigned to. `__setattr__()` is used when binding to an attribute of an object. Unless you're creating a descriptor, you won't use `__set__()`.

Comment: Thank you for that answer! It is simple but answers refuser's question regarding `__set__` and `__setattr_`. I am guessing that `__get__` and `__set__` could be used in interesting ways to abuse the language.

Answer (score 8):

If the getter/setter are really as trivial as that, then you shouldn't even bother with them: just use an instance variable.  If you do need a getter/setter that does something interesting, then you should switch to a property, as mgilson described.  Note that you can change from an instance variable to a property without anything that uses your code noticing the difference.  I.e., start with:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = None
```

And only change to the property-based accessors mgilson described if/when it turns out you need something interesting to happen when you get/set the attribute.

Comment: + 1 for recommending a simple instance variable. Python is not Java, and getter/setter (properties in Python) are used much less, only when they are actually needed.

Comment: @rubik "../only when the are actually needed." That's probably why I wrote "(if I need to)".

Answer (score 5):

Assume you've got `class Master` with an attribute `x` which is of `class Slave` and you want some code to be executed when you assign something to `x` as in `some_master.x = foo`. Where will this code be located? It can be in the class `Master`, in which case you use `__setattr__`. It can be also in the class `Slave`, so that it has a control on what is being assigned. In this case, you make `Slave` a [descriptor](http://docs.python.org/howto/descriptor.html) and use `__set__`.

Examples:

```
>>> class Master(object):
...     def __setattr__(self, name, val):
...         print "run code in Master: %s" % val
... 
>>> a = Master()
>>> a.x = 123
run code in Master: 123
```

compare to this:

```
>>> class Slave(object):
...     def __set__(self, obj, val):
...         print "run code in Slave: %s" % val
... 
>>> class Master2(object):
...     x = Slave()
... 
>>> b = Master2()
>>> b.x = 345
run code in Slave: 345
```

To answer the question which one is more pythonic, I'd say neither. If you need to actually **do** something, make it a function. Explicit > implicit.

```
 def update_param(a):
     update_stuff(a)
     and_calculate_some_thing(a)
     self.a = a
```

Comment: So rather than @x.setter\n def x(self, val):\n self.x=y I should update x through a function? That seems cumbersome if all I want to do is update some related value when x is set?

Comment: @refuser: as always with design questions, it depends on the concrete use case. In general, exposing the object's state is rarely a good idea.