# Python: differences among __setitem__ ; setattr ; set

Tags: python, class, attributes, setattr

simple explanations by examples would do where the 3 of them cannot be interchanged.

```
def __setitem__(self,**k):
        #self.val=k
        for key in k:
            self.val.setdefault(key,[]).extend(v for v in k[key])
```

Can the above step be done in iterations with setattr(obj,val[,can optional stuff come here??])

WHy not just create our own style and private methods?

```
def _add(self,**k):
    if isinstance(self, CClass):
        for key in k:
            self.val.setdefault(key,[]).extend(v for v in k[key])
```

Q: Where all a Class's scope allows these private methods to be accessed and used?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10707206/what-is-the-difference-between-set-and-setattr-in-python-and-when-should

Answer (score 3):

`__setitem__` can only be used for setting *one* item:

```
def __setitem__(self, key, value):
    self.val.setdefault(key,[]).append(value)
```

If you prefer to extend all at once with one call, you can build something like `dict`'s `.update()` method which takes an iterable and/or keyword arguments:

```
def update(self, it, **k):
    for key, val in it:
        self.val.setdefault(key,[]).extend(v for v in val)
    for key, val in k.iteritems():
        self.val.setdefault(key,[]).extend(v for v in val)
```

Comment: so u mean my first code is really not extending but appending right?

Comment: @user2290820 I think extending should be ok, but you should obey that the correct semantic is used: what should happen if you do `my_object[key] = something`.

Comment: because i want to extend to the current list,not overwrite or replace existing ones.im trying to find a way to add attributes dynamically.is there a way?