# Scope in Functions vs. Methods

Tags: python, python-3.x, scope

I am wondering why a method of a class doesn't look into its enclosing scope, if a name is not defined.

```
def test_scope_function():
    var = 5
    def print_var():
        print(var) # finds var from __test_scope_function__
    print_var()


globalvar = 5
class TestScopeGlobal:
    var = globalvar # finds globalvar from __main__

    @staticmethod
    def print_var():
        print(TestScopeGlobal.var)


class TestScopeClass():
    var = 5

    @staticmethod
    def print_var():
        print(var) # Not finding var, raises NameError

test_scope_function()
TestScopeGlobal.print_var()
TestScopeClass.print_var()
```

I would expect `TestScopeClass.print_var()` to print `5` since it can read `classvar` in the `TestScopeClass` body.

Why this behavior? And what should i read in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/classes.html?highlight=scope) to get to know about it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Scopes are searched [as follows](https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces):

> - the innermost scope, which is searched first, contains the local names
> - the scopes of any enclosing **functions**, which are searched starting with the nearest enclosing scope, contains non-local, but also non-global names
> - the next-to-last scope contains the current module’s global names
> - the outermost scope (searched last) is the namespace containing built-in names

(emphasis added).  Enclosing classes are not searched, because they are not listed.  This behavior is deliberate, because otherwise the [descriptor protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3798835/understanding-get-and-set-and-python-descriptors), which among other things provides the `self` argument to methods, would not have a chance to fire.

Answer (score 3):

Per [the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding) (emphasis mine):

> The scope of names defined in a class block is limited to the class block; it **does not extend to the code blocks of methods**