# callable object as method of a class - Can I get `self` to be the class that owns the method?

Tags: python

In python, a class instance can be used almost like a function, if it has a `__call__` method. I want to have a class `B` that has a method `A`, where `A` is the instance of a class with a `__call__` method. For comparison, I also define two other methods `foo` and `bar` in the "traditional" way (i.e. using `def`). Here is the code:

```
class A(object):
    def __call__(*args):
        print args

def foo(*args):
    print args

class B(object):
    A = A()
    foo = foo
    def bar(*args):
        print args
```

When I call any of the methods of `B`, they are passed a class instance as implicit first argument (which is conventionally called `self`).
Yet, I was surprised to find that `b.A()` gets passed an `A` instance, where I would have expected a `B` instance.

```
In [13]: b = B()

In [14]: b.A()
(<__main__.A object at 0xb6251e0c>,)

In [15]: b.foo()
(<__main__.B object at 0xb6251c0c>,)

In [16]: b.bar()
(<__main__.B object at 0xb6251c0c>,)
```

Is there a way (maybe a `functools` trick or similar) to bind `A()` in such a way that `b.A()` is passed a reference to the `b` object?

Please note that the example presented above is simplified for the purpose of illustrating my question. I'm not asking for advice on my actual implementation use case, which is different.

**Edit**: I get the same output, if I define my class `B` like this:

```
class B(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.A = A()
    foo = foo
    def bar(*args):
        print args
```

Comment: You've simplified it so much that we can't tell you if there's a better way of doing what you want done.

Comment: *"I was surprised to find"* - why? What else would it be passed?! You're calling *the attribute*, not the instance.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: There are certainly many different ways to do what I have done, and some of them might be "better" in terms of readability, others might be better in speed,... I appreciate your willingness to help, but the solution I use in my real code is good enough for you and I want to keep the question focussed.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: That's what I thought at first. When I make an instance of `A` in the `__init__` of `B` I get the same answer (see edit of my question). Should `b.A` not be an instance of `A` in this case? Obviously, I don't fully understand what is going on here, so please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Again, **why would you expect otherwise?!**

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Maybe my last comment did not fully answer your point. I expected that `b.foo` and `b.A` would look the same for the instance `b` because they are both callable objects (my understanding is that a function is an object, too). Thus, I expected that they both would get passed an reference to the instance `b`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is:

```
class B(object):
    A = A()
```

class `B` has a member named `A` that is an instance of `A`. When you do `B.A()`, it calls the method `__call__` of that `A` instance (that is confusingly named `A`); and since it is an `A` all the time, and `A`'s method, of course the actual object in `args` is an `A`.

---

What you're after is a [*descriptor*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3798835/understanding-get-and-set-and-python-descriptors); that is, `A` should have the magic method `__get__`; :

```
class A(object):
    def __get__(self, cls, instance):
        print(cls, instance)
        return self

class B(object):
    a = A()

b = B()
c = b.a
```

Now when `b.a` is executed, `__get__` method gets `B` and `b` as the `cls` and `instance` arguments, and whatever it returns is the value from the attribute lookup (the value that is stored in `c`) - it could return another instance, or even a function, or throw an `AttributeError` - up to you. To have another function that knows the `B` and `b`; you can do:

```
class A(object):
    def __get__(self, cls, instance):
        if instance is not None:
            def wrapper():
                print("I was called with", cls, "and", instance)
            return wrapper
        return self

class B(object):
    a = A()

B.a()
```

The code outputs:

```
I was called with <__main__.B object at 0x7f5d52a7b8> and <class '__main__.B'>
```

Task accomplished.

Comment: That's disappointing. It seems to me the behavior ought to be consistent between callable objects and functions. The instance of B should be passed as the second argument, making the A instance transparent to the caller. Without this, mocking attributes that can be either methods or data members is impossible without using callable(), which is prone to false positives.