# Difference between "wrapper" and "method" descriptors?

Tags: python

I was writing a code that finds "unbound methods" of a class using introspection and was surprised to see two different kinds of descriptors for builtin types:

```
>>> type(list.append), list.append
(<class 'method_descriptor'>, <method 'append' of 'list' objects>)
>>> type(list.__add__), list.__add__
(<class 'wrapper_descriptor'>, <slot wrapper '__add__' of 'list' objects>)
```

[Searching the docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/search.html?q=method_descriptor&check_keywords=yes&area=default) turned up very limited but interesting results:

1. [A note in the inspect module](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/inspect.html?highlight=wrapper_descriptor#inspect.getattr_static) that `inspect.getattr_static` doesn't resolve descriptors and includes a code that can be used to resolve them.
2. [an optimization made in python 2.4](https://docs.python.org/3.5/whatsnew/2.4.html?highlight=method_descriptor#optimizations) claiming that `method_descriptor` is **more efficient** than `wrapper_descriptor` but not explaining what they are:

   > The methods `list.__getitem__()`, `dict.__getitem__()`, and `dict.__contains__()` are now implemented as *method_descriptor* objects rather than *wrapper_descriptor* objects. **This form of access doubles their performance** and makes them more suitable for use as arguments to functionals: `map(mydict.__getitem__, keylist)`.

The difference in performance quite intrigued me, **clearly there is a difference** so I went looking for additional information.

Neither of these types are in the module `types`:

```
>>> import types
>>> type(list.append) in vars(types).values()
False
>>> type(list.__add__) in vars(types).values()
False
```

using `help` doesn't provide any useful information:

```
>>> help(type(list.append))
Help on class method_descriptor in module builtins:

class method_descriptor(object)
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
    <generic descriptions for>
      __call__, __get__, __getattribute__, __reduce__, and __repr__
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Data descriptors defined here:
 |  
 |  __objclass__
 |  
 |  __text_signature__

>>> help(type(list.__add__))
Help on class wrapper_descriptor in module builtins:

class wrapper_descriptor(object)
 |  Methods defined here:
 |  
    <generic descriptions for>
      __call__, __get__, __getattribute__, __reduce__, and __repr__
 |  
 |  ----------------------------------------------------------------------
 |  Data descriptors defined here:
 |  
 |  __objclass__
 |  
 |  __text_signature__
```

[Searching the internet](https://www.google.ca/webhp?hl=en&ictx=2&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjjhY6nnqjNAhUi7YMKHdpBCTsQPQgD#hl=en&q=python%20method%20descriptor%20vs%20wrapper%20descriptor) only came up with results about "what is a descriptor" or vague references to the specific types involved.

So my question is:

**What is the actual difference between `<class 'method_descriptor'>` and `<class 'wrapper_descriptor'>`?**

Comment: Don't trust `inspect` regarding descriptors. See https://bugs.python.org/issue26103 (also relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3798835/541136 )

Comment: @AaronHall I figured including one but not the other was probably an oversight but wasn't sure, I will revert to version that didn't point out the inconsistency in inspect docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an implementation detail. At C level, a built-in type like `list` defines methods like `append` by name through an array of `PyMethodDef` structs, while special methods like `__add__` are defined more indirectly.

`__add__` corresponds to a function pointer in either of the two slots `sq_concat` in the type's `tp_as_sequence` or `nb_add` in the type's `tp_as_number`. If a type defines one of those slots, Python generates a `wrapper_descriptor` wrapping that slot for the `__add__` method of the Python-level API.

The wrapping necessary for type slots and `PyMethodDef` structs is a bit different; for example, two slots could correspond to one method, or one slot could correspond to six methods. Slots also don't carry their method names with them, while the method name is one of the fields in a `PyMethodDef`. Since different code is needed for the two cases, Python uses different wrapper types to wrap them.

If you want to see the code, both `method_descriptor` and `wrapper_descriptor` are implemented in [`Objects/descrobject.c`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Objects/descrobject.c), with struct typedefs in [`Include/descrobject.h`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Include/descrobject.h). You can see the code that initializes the wrappers in [`Objects/typeobject.c`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Objects/typeobject.c), where `PyType_Ready` delegates to `add_operators` for `wrapper_descriptor`s and `add_methods` for `method_descriptor`s.

Comment: Most of this sounds correct but what do you mean "Slots also don't carry their method names with them"? I can still do `list.__add__.__name__` and get back `'__add__'`

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen: The C-level `sq_concat` slot only holds a function pointer. The slot wrapper has to hold the `__add__` name.

Comment: Could you add links to the source code that support this information? The difference being an implementation detail is definitely the correct answer since Jython doesn't have a `wrapper_descriptor` but I still don't have any references that describe how either of the classes work.

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen: Links added.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `method_descriptor` and `wrapper_descriptor` are a kind of callables that are available in CPython. 
The difference between them seems to be simple
`method_descriptor` is apparently used for the methods of built-in
(implemented in C) objects:

```
set.__dict__['union'].__class__
<class 'wrapper_descriptor'>
```

`wrapper_descriptor` is used for example the operators of built-in types:

```
int.__dict__['__add__'].__class__.
<class 'method-wrapper'>
```

[This is the place](http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.python.devel/133486) where I found this information.

Comment: I understand what `method_wrapper` is, it is the built in equivelent to `<class 'method'>` which is used for bound methods, I am asking the difference between `method_descriptor` and `wrapper_descriptor`.