# Subfunction referencing without object declation

Tags: python

I've got a class of the form:

```
class MyClass(object):
  def curves(self):
    def plot(self):
       plot a graph
       return something
    return a pd.DataFrame
```

What I want to do is define something I can call with `instance_of_my_class.curves.plot()`

Do I need to define curves as an object to make this possible? I'm looking for the shortest way to do it, as this is syntactic sugar only.

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to call `instance_of_my_class.curves.plot()` it has to be an object, or at least something with settable attributes. Currently, your `plot()` is only defined inside the environment of the `curves()` function when it is called. ie.`plot()` is only created when you call  `curves()`, and only accessible within `curves()`

Comment: Is `plot` using any of the variables within `curves`, e.g. `self` or whatever else there might be that you don't show in this short example? If so, what should be the value of those variables when called "outside" of `curves`? If not, why define it within `curves` in the first place?

Comment: @jojo Class methods don’t get the instance passed?

Comment: @jojo And how does that help when `plot` is supposed to act on the `MyClass` instance?

Comment: @poke: no one said it's supposed to, no?! But you can access the class instance `MyClass` from within `plot`, no problemo. Just don't try to access `MyClass` objects as this might lead to problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to add a level of hierarchy, `curves` needs to be an actual object, yes. There is no difference between `foo.curves.plot()` and the following:

```
c = foo.curves
c.plot()
```

So `foo.curves` needs to be an object that has a `plot` method.

Also, since the method is called on the `curves` object, the method will be bound to that object. So unless you set it up that way, the `curves` object will not have access to your actual class.

You could pass the instance in the `curves` constructor though:

```
class Curves (object):
    def __init__ (self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
    def plot (self):
        self.parent._plot()

class MyClass (object):
    def __init__ (self):
        self.curves = Curves(self)
    def _plot (self):
        print('Actual plot implementation')
```

Then you can use it as `foo.curves.plot()`:

```
>>> foo = MyClass()
>>> foo.curves.plot()
Actual plot implementation
```

---

You could also automate this a bit by using a [descriptor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3798835/understanding-get-and-set-and-python-descriptors) for `curves`. For example, this is a possible solution:

```
class Accessor (object):
    def __init__ (self, prefix = ''):
        self.prefix = prefix
    def __get__ (self, instance, owner):
        return AccessorDelegate(instance, self.prefix)

class AccessorDelegate (object):
    def __init__ (self, instance, prefix):
        self.instance = instance
        self.prefix = prefix
    def __getattr__ (self, name):
        return getattr(self.instance, self.prefix + name)
```

The benefit is obviously that you only need to define those a single time and then they’ll work for all your classes. You would use it like this in your class:

```
class MyClass (object):
    curves = Accessor('_curves_')

    def _curves_plot(self):
        print('Implementation of curves.plot')
```

Used exactly as above:

```
>>> foo = MyClass()
>>> foo.curves.plot()
Implementation of curves.plot
```