# Setting GenericForeignKey field value in Django

Tags: python, django, django-contenttypes

I've been reading lately about the generic relations. I know that `GenericForeignKey` is to define and manaeg the generic relation using `ForeignKey` and `PositiveIntegerField` fields. I dove into the source code in search for the `__set__` method of the `GenericForeignKey` to see how does it work.

Here is the snippet for `GenericForeignKey.__set__()`:

```
def __set__(self, instance, value):
    ct = None
    fk = None
    if value is not None:
        ct = self.get_content_type(obj=value)
        fk = value._get_pk_val()
    setattr(instance, self.ct_field, ct)
    setattr(instance, self.fk_field, fk)
    setattr(instance, self.cache_attr, value)
```

and model definition from django docs [example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/contenttypes/):

```
class TaggedItem(models.Model):
    tag = models.SlugField()
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

### Question:

When I assign value of `guido` to the `content_object` then what is the value of each of these paremeters: `self`, `instance` and `value` in the `GenericForeignKey.__set__()`?

Is `self=<GenericForeignKey: 1>`, `instance='content_object'`, and `value=<User: guido>`?

```
>>> guido = User.objects.get(username='Guido')
>>> t = TaggedItem(content_object=guido, tag='bdfl')
>>> t.save()
```

Comment: Read up on [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html)!  Here's  a useful answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34554353/674039

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `__set__` method is for [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html).

The following simple example will show what the arguments passed to `__set__` are:

```
class MyDescriptor:
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        print((self, instance, value))

class MyClass:
    attr = MyDescriptor()

inst = MyClass()
inst.attr = "foo"
```

You'll get something like:

```
<__main__.MyDescriptor object at 0x000002017192AD68>,   # self
<__main__.MyClass object at 0x000002017192ACF8>,        # instance
'foo'                                                   # value
```

Specifically:

- `self` is the instance of the `MyDescriptor` descriptor (`MyClass.attr`),
- `instance` is the instance of the `MyClass` class (`inst`), and
- `value` is what you're setting the attribute to (`"foo"`).

See a more thorough example [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#descriptor-example).

So, without similarly diving into the Django code, it would seem that:

- `self` is the instance of the `GenericForeignKey` descriptor (`TaggedItem.content_object`),
- `instance` is the instance of the `TaggedItem` class, and
- `value` is what you're setting the attribute to.

But note that, with this line:

```
t = TaggedItem(content_object=guido, tag='bdfl')
```

It looks like you're creating a `TaggedItem`, which *creates* a descriptor with this line

```
content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

So, at least from the code you posted, the `__set__` method won't be called.  Instead `GenericForeignKey`'s `__init__` method would be called.

To call `GenericForeignKey`'s `__set__` method, you'd need to do have an instance of a class (call it `inst`) that had a `GenericForeignKey` descriptor as an attribute (call it `attr`), then write something like:

```
inst.attr = "not guido"
```

Then, the `__set__` method of the `GenericForeignKey` descriptor *would* be called.

Comment: That makes sense! However it does not explicitly answer the question, it gives you the tools to understand what I was asking about.

Comment: @an0o0nym regarding "When I assign value of guido to the content_object then what is the value of each of these paremeters: self, instance and value in the GenericForeignKey.__set__()?" the answer sort of addresses it.  It tells you what the parameters *would be* if it was called, but I explained why it probably wouldn't be called.