# Python - __get__ is not called for my class

Tags: python, python-descriptors

Here is my code :

```
class Argument :
    def __init__( self, argType, argHelp = None ) :
        self.type = argType
        self.help = argHelp
    def __get__(self, obj, type=None):
        print("__get__")
        return self.type

a  = Argument( "my_ret_value" , argHelp = "some help text "  )
```

What I want is this to return `my_ret_value` but instead I get :

```
<__main__.Argument instance at 0x7ff608ab24d0>
```

I've read [Python Descriptors examples](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/descriptor.html#descriptor-example) and if I change my code to follow that it works - but why can't I do it on my class as it is? Is there any other way?

EDIT :

Thanks for the comments, I had not understand it very well. Could `__repr__` solve my issue?

What I want is that I am changing a string value into an Object, I want to treat this object as a string, with some extra attributes.

Comment: Have you tried it? : `a.__get__()`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding \_\_get\_\_ and \_\_set\_\_ and Python descriptors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3798835/understanding-get-and-set-and-python-descriptors)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your decriptor class as follows:

```
class B:
    a = Argument("my_ret_value", argHelp="some help text")

b = B()
b.a
# __get__
# 'my_ret_value'
```

When set as class attribute on another class and accessed via an instance of said class, then the `__get__` method of the descriptor is called. See the [Descriptor How-To Guide](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html).

Comment: thanks, I can try that! If I want though to use a single class, maybe I can access it by overriding `__repr__` ? Can you check my edit?