# Need help on python Descriptor functionality

Tags: python, python-descriptors

I'm trying to solve a problem using python Descriptors.. 
Code is as below

```
class Celsius( object ):
    def __init__( self, value=0.0 ):
        self.value= float(value)
    def __get__( self, instance, owner ):
        return float(self.value)
    def __set__( self, instance, value ):
        self.value= float(value)

class Fahrenheit( object ):
    def __get__( self, instance, owner ):
        return (instance.celsius * 9 / 5 + 32.0)
    def __set__( self, instance, value ):
        instance.celsius= (float(value)-32.0) * 5 / 9

class Temperature( object ):
    def __init__(self, fahrenheit):
        self.fahrenheit = fahrenheit

    fahrenheit = Fahrenheit()
    celsius = Celsius()

t1 = Temperature(32)
print(t1.fahrenheit, t1.celsius)
t1.celsius = 0
print(t1.fahrenheit, t1.celsius)
```

Expected O/P is

```
32 0.0
32.0 0.0
```

But I get

```
32.0 0.0
32.0 0.0
```

Please help where should I change or if there is any other better way.

Comment: They both return `float`s, why would you expect an `int` there?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding \_\_get\_\_ and \_\_set\_\_ and Python descriptors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3798835/understanding-get-and-set-and-python-descriptors)

Comment: The output you say you're getting is what I'd expect from your code. Why do you think you should get `32` from `t1.fahrenheit` when you first access it? Also, that descriptor design is very weird, as every instance of `Temperature` will share the same temperature values (since they live in the `Celsius` descriptor instance). It would be much more natural to save the underlying value in the instance somewhere.

Comment: I need to get the O/P as 32 0.0 32.0 0.0 . I'm trying to figure out how to do it

Comment: I'm looking for what to change in my code to get the desired O/P

Comment: Please Explain why you want (and expect) no decimal portion to print on the first number output.

Comment: its a part of python learning exercise I'm trying to solve..

Comment: Frankly, it sounds like your exercise is bugged.

Comment: Is there a better way to write the code to get the expected O/P (without editing the print statement).. I am new comer to python and trying learn by googling and posting questions..

Answer (score 0):

With no explanation of why you want the output you desire...just that you WANT that output, you can get it by changing the last four lines of your code to:

```
t1 = Temperature(32)
print(int(t1.fahrenheit), t1.celsius)
t1.celsius = 0
print(t1.fahrenheit, t1.celsius)
```

Output:

```
32 0.0
32.0 0.0
```

I assume you want something other than this, but I can't figure out what you might want.  The output you're getting from your code as is is perfectly reasonable.

Answer (score 0):

class Celsius:
    def **get**(self, instance, owner):
        return 5 * (instance.fahrenheit - 32) /9

```
def __set__(self, instance, value):
    instance.fahrenheit = 32 + 9 * value/5
```

class Temperature:
    celsius = Celsius()

```
def __init__(self, initial_f):
    self.fahrenheit = initial_f
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you assign something to `fahrenheit`, the `__set__()` method of `Fahrenheit` delegates to `instance.celsius`. All of the methods on `Celsius` convert to `float`. If you want your examples to work as you expect, you'll need `Celsius` to delegate to `instance.fahrenheit` instead while still doing it's `float` conversions, maybe only only in `__get__()` if that's what you want.

So, to sum up, store in `Fahrenheit` type without type conversion, and delegate to `Fahrenheit` from `Celsius`.

As some others have noted, your descriptor design makes it so that all instances of `Temperature` will store the same value. If you want different instances to hold different values, you'll need to save the value either directly on the instance under a different name (typically, it would be `_fahrenheit` in this situation) or in a kind of dictionary where the key is `instance`.

Lastly, for this kind of situation where there's a value shared between two descriptors and they're not likely to be reused somewhere else, I would go the `property` route.