# How to use add a descriptor to catch and raise TypeError upon attribute fetches?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, descriptor, python-descriptors

Without making changes to the class, implement a descriptor, that checks if the value fetched to an instance attribute has the correct type.

I have found a related post, but I don't know how to implement it in my case.
[Understanding __get__ and __set__ and Python descriptors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3798835/understanding-get-and-set-and-python-descriptors)

```
...
class ArticleField:

    def __init__(self, field_type: typing.Type[typing.Any]):
        pass


class Article:

    def __init__(self, title: str, author: str, publication_date: datetime.datetime, content: str):
        self.title = title
        self.author = author
        self.publication_date = publication_date
        self.content = content
...
```

Like this:

```
>>> class Article:
...     age = ArticleField(field_type=int)
>>> article = Article(...)
>>> article.age = "some string"
Traceback (most recent call last):
    ...
TypeError: expected an instance of type 'int' for attribute 'age', got 'str' instead
```

Comment: Have you tried implementing the `__get__` and `__set__` methods on your descriptor like the question you linked?

Comment: @Iain Shelvington I changed my question to a more specific `TypeError` upon attribute *fetches. My descriptor needs to manage specific attributes. Can you point me at the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Below may match your request.

```py
class ArticleField:

    def __init__(self, field_type: typing.Type[typing.Any]):
        self.field_type = field_type
        self.value = None
    
    def __get__(self, instance, owner=None):
        return self.value
    
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        if isinstance(value, self.field_type):
            self.value = value
        else:
            raise TypeError(f'Invalid type {type(value)}')
```