# Explicit call to __call__ works and uses __init__

Tags: python, python-3.x, operator-overloading, language-lawyer

I'm learning overloading in Python 3.X and to better understand the topic, I wrote the following code that works in 3.X but not in 2.X. I expected the below code to fail since I've not defined `__call__` for class `Test`. But to my surprise, it works and prints `"constructor called"`. [Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/WdlsPhoh3).

```
class Test: 
    def __init__(self):
        print("constructor called")
#Test.__getitem__()  #error as expected

Test.__call__() #this works in 3.X(but not in 2.X) and prints "constructor called"! WHY THIS DOESN'T GIVE ERROR in 3.x?
```

So my question is that how/why exactly does this code work in 3.x but not in 2.x. I mean I want to know the mechanics behind what is going on.

More importantly, why `__init__` is being used here when I am using `__call__`?

Comment: Well, `__call__` is used when you use `()` on an object directly - e.g. `Test()` - does that look like anything familiar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 3.x:

### About attribute lookup, `type` and `object`

Every time an attribute is looked up on an object, Python follows a process like this:

1. Is it directly a part of the actual data in the object? If so, use that and stop.
2. Is it directly a part of the object's class? If so, hold onto that for step 4.
3. Otherwise, check the object's class for `__getattr__` and `__getattribute__` overrides, look through base classes in the MRO, etc. (This is a massive simplification, of course.)
4. If something was found in step 2 or 3, [check if it has a `__get__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3798835). If it does, look that up (yes, that means starting over at step 1 for the attribute named `__get__` on that object), call it, and use its return value. Otherwise, use what was returned directly.

Functions have a `__get__` automatically; it is used to implement method binding. Classes are objects; that's why it's possible to look up attributes in them. That is: the purpose of the `class Test:` block is to **define a data type**; the code creates an object named `Test` which **represents the data type that was defined**.

But since the `Test` class is an object, it must be an instance of some  class. That class is called `type`, and has a built-in implementation.

```
>>> type(Test)
<class 'type'>
```

Notice that `type(Test)` is not a function call. Rather, the name `type` is pre-defined to refer to a class, which every other class created in user code is (by default) an instance of.

In other words, `type` is the default **metaclass**: the class of classes.

```
>>> type
<class 'type'>
```

One may ask, what class does `type` belong to? The answer is surprisingly simple - **itself**:

```
>>> type(type) is type
True
```

Since the above examples call `type`, we conclude that `type` is callable. To be callable, it must have a `__call__` attribute, and it does:

```
>>> type.__call__
<slot wrapper '__call__' of 'type' objects>
```

When `type` is called with a single argument, it looks up the argument's class (roughly equivalent to accessing the `__class__` attribute of the argument). When called with three arguments, it creates a new instance of `type`, i.e., a new class.

### How does `type` work?

Because this is digging right at the core of the language (allocating memory for the object), it's not quite possible to implement this in pure Python, at least for the reference C implementation (and I have no idea what sort of magic is going on in PyPy here). But we can *approximately* model the `type` class like so:

```
def _validate_type(obj, required_type, context):
    if not isinstance(obj, required_type):
        good_name = required_type.__name__
        bad_name = type(obj).__name__
        raise TypeError(f'{context} must be {good_name}, not {bad_name}')

class type:
    def __new__(cls, name_or_obj, *args):
        # __new__ implicitly gets passed an instance of the class, but
        # `type` is its own class, so it will be `type` itself.
        if len(args) == 0: # 1-argument form: check the type of an existing class.
            return obj.__class__
        # otherwise, 3-argument form: create a new class.
        try:
            bases, attrs = args
        except ValueError:
            raise TypeError('type() takes 1 or 3 arguments')
        _validate_type(name, str, 'type.__new__() argument 1')
        _validate_type(bases, tuple, 'type.__new__() argument 2')
        _validate_type(attrs, dict, 'type.__new__() argument 3')

        # This line would not work if we were actually implementing
        # a replacement for `type`, as it would route to `object.__new__(type)`,
        # which is explicitly disallowed. But let's pretend it does...
        result = super().__new__()
        # Now, fill in attributes from the parameters.
        result.__name__ = name_or_obj
        # Assigning to `__bases__` triggers a lot of other internal checks!
        result.__bases__ = bases
        for name, value in attrs.items():
            setattr(result, name, value)
        return result
    del __new__.__get__ # `__new__`s of builtins don't implement this.

    def __call__(self, *args):
        return self.__new__(self, *args)
    # this, however, does have a `__get__`.
```

### What happens (conceptually) when we call the class (`Test()`)?

1. `Test()` uses function-call syntax, but it's not a function. To figure out what should happen, we translate the call into `Test.__class__.__call__(Test)`. (We use `__class__` directly here, because translating the function call using `type` - asking `type` to categorize itself - would end up in endless recursion.)
2. `Test.__class__` is `type`, so this becomes `type.__call__(Test)`.
3. `type` contains a `__call__` directly (`type` is its own class, remember?), so it's used directly - we don't go through the `__get__` descriptor. We call the function, with `Test` as `self`, and no other arguments. (We have a function now, so we don't need to translate the function call syntax again. We *could* - given a function `func`, `func.__class__.__call__.__get__(func)` gives us an instance of an unnamed builtin "method wrapper" type, which does the same thing as `func` when called. Repeating the loop on the method wrapper creates a separate method wrapper that still does the same thing.)
4. This attempts the call `Test.__new__(Test)` (since `self` was bound to `Test`). `Test.__new__` isn't explicitly defined in `Test`, but since `Test` is a class, we don't look in `Test`'s class (`type`), but instead in `Test`'s base (`object`).
5. `object.__new__(Test)` exists, and does magical built-in stuff to allocate memory for a new instance of the `Test` class, make it possible to assign attributes to that instance (even though `Test` is a subtype of `object`, which disallows that), and set its `__class__` to `Test`.

Similarly, when we call `type`, the same logical chain turns `type(Test)` into `type.__class__.__call__(type, Test)` into `type.__call__(type, Test)`, which forwards to `type.__new__(type, Test)`. This time, there is a `__new__` attribute directly in `type`, so this doesn't fall back to looking in `object`. Instead, with `name_or_obj` being set to `Test`, we simply return `Test.__class__`, i.e., `type`. And with separate `name, bases, attrs` arguments, `type.__new__` instead creates an instance of `type`.

### Finally: what happens when we call `Test.__call__()` explicitly?

If there's a `__call__` defined in the class, it gets used, since it's found directly. This will fail, however, because there aren't enough arguments: the descriptor protocol isn't used since the attribute was found directly, so `self` isn't bound, and so that argument is missing.

If there *isn't* a `__call__` method defined, then we look in `Test`'s class, i.e., `type`. There's a `__call__` there, so the rest proceeds like steps 3-5 in the previous section.

Comment: TODO: find or create an appropriate canonical that has the full, detailed attribute lookup process; reference that here instead of duplicating the material. Similarly for explaining `type`.

Comment: @Fractalism thanks for the copyedit. It was overall quite good, but I changed a few things back. In particular, "make it possible to assign attributes" and "set its `__class__` to `Test`" are correct. Here, "make" and "set" are [parallel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parallelism_(grammar)) to "allocate" - the ability to set attributes, and the setting of the `__name__` attribute, are not *consequences of* the memory allocation, but separate things that are also done by `object.__new__` once the memory is allocated.

Comment: I see your point, good catch! And glad you liked it ;)

Answer (score 0):

In Python 3.x, every class is implicitely a child of the builtin class `object`. And at least in the CPython implementation, the `object` class has a `__call__` method which is defined in its metaclass `type`.

That means that `Test.__call__()` is exactly the same as `Test()` and will return a new `Test` object, calling your custom `__init__` method.

In Python 2.x classes are by default *old-style* classes and are not child of `object`. Because of that `__call__` is not defined. You can get the same behaviour in Python 2.x by using *new style* classes, meaning by making an explicit inheritance on object:

```
# Python 2 new style class
class Test(object):
    ...
```

Comment: This is subtly wrong. While `object.__call__` can be used, and is in a meaningful sense "defined in its metaclass `type`", that's a method *of `object` itself*, not of `object` instances. When `Test.__call__` is looked up in the example, this lookup process **doesn't have anything to do with** `object`; it checks directly in `type`, finds the `.__call__` attribute and creates a bound method - both `Test` and `object` do this directly. If `type` didn't have a `__call__`, *then* the lookup chain would proceed *from `call` to `object`*, since `type` is a subclass of `object`.

Comment: (But we'd have much bigger problems in that hypothetical, like getting from there to `type.__new__`. We can also easily show that this doesn't happen, because `object.__call__` doesn't accept the same arguments that `type.__call__` does.