# In Python, what is a method_descriptor?

Tags: python, methods

In Python, what is a method_descriptor (in plain English)?

I had this error, and I can't really find any information on it:

```
*** TypeError: can't pickle method_descriptor objects
```

Comment: Could you post the code that led to this error?

Comment: I suspect you forgot your function call parentheses somewhere, so your code is trying to pickle a method instead of its return value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Understanding \_\_get\_\_ and \_\_set\_\_ and Python descriptors](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3798835/understanding-get-and-set-and-python-descriptors)

Comment: I am not interested in debugging this error, and I found all the answers to these other questions unclear. 

I just want to know what a method_descriptor is, in plain English.

Answer (score 5):

Switch to [`dill`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dill).

> I am not interested in debugging this error...

**You should be.** If you're uninterested in debugging errors, you're in the wrong field. For the sake of polite argumentation, let's charitably assume you authored [that comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27068154/in-python-what-is-a-method-descriptor#comment42847586_27068154) under the duress of an unreasonable deadline. (*It happens.*)

The standard `pickle` module is incapable of serializing so-called "exotic types," including but presumably *not* limited to: functions with `yields`, nested functions, lambdas, cells, methods, unbound methods, modules, ranges, slices, `code` objects, `methodwrapper` objects, `dictproxy` objects, `getsetdescriptor` objects, `memberdescriptor` objects, `wrapperdescriptor` objects, `notimplemented` objects, `ellipsis` objects, `quit` objects, and (*...wait for it!*) `method_descriptor` objects.

All is not lost, however. The third-party [`dill` package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dill) *is* capable of serializing all of these types and substantially more. Since `dill` is a drop-in replacement for `pickle`, globally replacing all calls across your codebase to the `pickle.dump()` function with the equivalent `dill.dump()` function *should* suffice to pickle the problematic method descriptors in question.

> I just want to know what a `method_descriptor` is, in plain English.

**No, you don't.** There *is* no plain-English explanation of method descriptors, because the [descriptor protocol](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html) underlying method descriptors is deliciously dark voodoo.

It's voodoo, because it has to be; it's the fundamental basis for Python's core implementation of functions, properties, static methods, and class methods. It's dark, because only a dwindling cabal of secretive Pythonistas are actually capable of correctly implementing a descriptor in the wild. It's delicious, because the power that [data descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#descriptor-protocol) in particular provide is nonpareil in the Python ecosystem.

Fortunately, you don't *need* to know what method descriptors are to pickle them. You only need to switch to [`dill`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dill).

Comment: Oh, please. Stop calling descriptors voodoo. At least for a basic understanding it is enough to say that they override the member access operator (the dot, as in `obj.member`). And you can read a member, write to it, or delete it - hence the `__get__`, `__set__` and `__del__`. It is pretty much plain English

Answer (score 0):

method_descriptor is a normal class with 
`__get__`, `__set__` and `__del__` methods.
You can check the link for more info at 
[Static vs instance methods of str in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1180303/static-vs-instance-methods-of-str-in-python)

Comment: I think the last code snippet in the link explains it (but I'm just pattern matching).  The naming seems pretty bad, but I guess method_descriptor is just the type of a method that is attached to a class (only (as opposed to an instance of the class)).